# How do I install HP Smart Storage Administrator (hpssa) on a Proliant N40L running Ubuntu Server 14.10?

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP Proliant N40L MicroServer with an HP Smart Array P410 raid card. The boot drive is an SSD running Ubuntu Server 14.10.

The P410 is getting hung up while initializing. From what I've read, the resolution is to install [hppsa](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man4/hpsa.4.html) from [HP's mcp repo](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/project/mcp/).

I added the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, updated apt, and generated keys:

```
deb http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo/mcp/ubuntu trusty/current non-free
```

When attempting to install hp-health (a dependency of hpssacli) I get the following error:

```
Setting up hp-health (10.0.0.1.3-4.) ...
  Trying to identify the Product Name.../etc/init.d/hp-health: line 461: [: : integer expression expected

  ERROR: This server is NOT supported!
  Error: No supported management controller found
invoke-rc.d: initscript hp-health, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package hp-health (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hp-health
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**`/etc/init.d/hp-health @ 140:`**

```
if [ "$PRODNUM" -ge 100 -a "$PRODNUM" -lt 200 ] ; then  # TRUE only if the server is 100 series
```

Based on that comment, it looks like hp-health only supports the 100 Series of Proliants. However,N40L with a P410 is pretty common from what I can tell.

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is it Ubuntu 14.10? Did I select the wrong version or distro on the MCP repo?

---

**Edit:**

When I just try to install `hpssacli` I get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../hpssacli_2.0-16.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hpssacli (2.0-16.0) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the one package you need: `hpssacli` or the older `hpacucli`. There shouldn't be a dependency on anything else. You definitely can't get hp-health running on the hardware you have. It's not meant for that equipment.

Comment: I started with that but I was getting the following:  `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. Edit: I updated my answer to give the full output of the failed install

Comment: I think my apt repo was all screwed up from me selecting the wrong distro earlier. I did a purge on all of hp's tools, downloaded the deb directly and was able to get it installed. Thanks.